# Use regex to capture "keyword args"

Tags: python, regex

I have a string formatted like this

```
s="""
stkcode="10001909" marketid="sh" isstop="S 01" turnover="0" contractid="000000" time="84445850"
"""
```

I want to capture all the "keyword args" substrings in it, i.e., `stkcode="10001909"`, `isstop="S 01"`. Note that a plain `s.split()` won't work because of possible white spaces in certain field values, for example `isstop="S 01"`. The correct way to go seems to be `re.split`, but I don't know how to write the appropriate regex. Can anyone help? Thanks!

**edit**
To add more info: we are guaranteed there is no `"` in each entry value. **Actually, we only need a "protective" split, i.e. only split the whitespace outside of a pairing `"`.**

**EDIT: XML is the way to go, not regex. Apologies**

My original data comprises many lines of `Timestamp + some aux info + an XML string`. So it cannot be directly parsed by an XML parser and has to be read line by line as strings. So I initially thought just stick with string and regex for each (relatively easy) single string. But I was wrong apparently. And XML parser is the way to go for sure.

Comment: You should really be using an XML parser for XML parsing.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks but I don't think it's conventional xml string because they don't have tags for each field. Maybe I should remove the mention of XML to focus on the real problem.

Comment: "because they don't have tags for each field" - what? What are you talking about? Are you unaware of the existence of XML attributes?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica yes of course i know there're xml attribs. However my problem is to parse the *string* of the `record` attribute, not parsing the xml itself. The string that needs to be parsed is unrelated to XML per se.

Comment: What the regex needs to look like depends on what the underlying format is; we'd need a *specification*, not an example, to be confident that corner cases are correctly handled -- with only an example of the *expected* case, we can't even know what the corner cases even are. So, to at least be able to start in the right direction -- which software is generating this data? Does it provide a specification of the format in question?

Comment: ...f/e, what happens if the value contains a `"` inside the quoted string? Does it become `&quot;`? Does it become `\"`? Does it become something else? Does it use single quotes instead of double quotes when there are double quotes in the data but no single quotes? Do you have a *formal guarantee* that double quotes in the data can't possibly happen? Etc; without a spec, any answer is relying on guesses in a way I'd never want to happen in real, production code (and would be very angry with any business partner I was integrating with who introduced bugs based on such guesses).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy They won't have `"` which can be guaranteed, because of they way the data is constructed. I will add an edit in the post.

Comment: The clarification is helpful. With so casual a spec, I'd almost be tempted to use `shlex.split()`, and then pass each element in the returned list through `result.split('=', 2)` to get a key/value pair.

Comment: "However my problem is to parse the string of the record attribute, not parsing the xml itself." - That distinction doesn't work the way you think it does. An XML parser is the right tool for this parsing.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica thanks for the suggestion. I will try taking a look at `ElementTree` to see if it can more easily get to the desired results.

Comment: I'm *hoping* the OP means they have something like `<record someattr="stkcode=&quot;1000119109&quot; marketid=&quot;sh&quot; ..."/>`, and they're asking how to parse the string in the attribute after their XML parser already decodes it. Otherwise, the question is indeed going at this very much the wrong way.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica Bravo! works like a charm. It seems that xml parser does the job nicely and without effort, and all i have to do is to follow down the tree until i get to the correct root. Thanks!

Comment: @Vim, ...maybe add your own answer to that effect (and showing a concrete example)? It'd have my +1 (albeit maybe not added until morning; about to put the laptop away for the night).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy my original data is kind of like `Timestamp + some aux info + an XML string`. So it cannot be directly parsed by an XML parser and has to be read line by line as strings. So I initially thought just stick with string and regex for each (relatively easy) single string. But I was wrong apparently. And XML parser **is** the way to go for sure. You are right.

Answer (score 0):

```
re.findall(r'((?!\<).*?)="(.*?)"', s)
```

Produces:

```
[('stkcode', '10001909'),
(' marketid', 'sh'),
(' isstop', 'S 01'),
(' turnover', '0'),
(' contractid', '000000'),
(' time', '84445850')]
```

Regex Explanation:

`(...)="(...)"`
Matches everything in this format, the kwarg format you've defined

Now the first group:
`((?!\<).*?)` will match all characters (`.*?`) except for the leading bracket (`(?!\<)`)

And the second group:
`(.*?)`
will just match all characters. The closing bracket is outside of the the quotes of the original matching pattern, so you don't have to worry about it.

EDIT:

To ignore whitespace around characters add this reverse matching group
`(?!\s)`
Not sure where whitespace would appear in your strings, but this new regex would handle it in every relevant place:

`((?!\<)(?!\s).*?(?!\s))="(?!\s)(.*?)(?!\s)`

Comment: Thanks, is there any way to remove the whitespace in the field name, like `' contractid'`, in the regex step

Comment: Sure, you can add a reverse match group just like the one for `<`, but to ignore whitespace `\s`, see edit